# Can I merge 2 dataframes with 2 same column labels using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here's my dataframes:

```
df1
Campaign                               Ad Group            Sales
AMZ CT BR Leather Shoes ABCDEFG1234   [leather shoes]      $10
AMZ CT BR Leather Shoes ABCDEFG1234   "leather shoes"      $10
AMZ CT NB Leather Shoes ABCDEFG1234   [leather shoes]      $20
AMZ OG BR Bag HGIJK567                 bag                 $30
AMZ OG NB Bag HGIJK567 Desktop         bag                 $40

df2
Campaign                              Ad Group             Spend        
GA BR Leather Shoes ABCDEFG1234      [leather shoes]        $5      
GA BR Leather Shoes ABCDEFG1234      "leather shoes"        $5
GA NB Leather Shoes ABCDEFG1234      [leather shoes]        $6
GA BR Bag HGIJK567                    bag                   $7
GA NB Bag HGIJK567 Desktop            bag                   $8
```

Here's the result I like when I merge the 2 dataframes:

```
df3
Campaign                             Ad Group          Spend   Sales
CT BR Leather Shoes ABCDEFG1234     [leather shoes]     $5      $10
CT BR Leather Shoes ABCDEFG1234     "leather shoes"     $5      $10    
CT NB Leather Shoes ABCDEFG1234     [leather shoes]     $6      $20
OG BR Bag HGIJK567                   bag                $7      $30
OG NB Bag HGIJK567 Desktop           bag                $8      $40
```

I would like to combine the values of the campaigns and ad groups in the merged dataframe.

Comment: `df3 = df1.assign(Spend=df2.Sales)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I get an error that says "DataFrame object has no attribute..."